Downgrade binary in TeX Live with `tlmgr restore`
I need to downgrade biblatex/biber to their previous versions (3.19/2.19).
I was originally on biblatex 3.20 and biber 2.20. Following this answer: tlmgr restore showed that I had backups were available.
However, after running sudo tlmgr restore biber 68188 and sudo tlmgr restore biblatex 66403, the biber binary somehow did not get downgraded.
tlmgr apparently thinks that biber is downgraded to the matching version, however, actually running the biber binary shows that it is not:
> tlmgr info biber
cat-version: 2.19

> biber --version
biber version: 2.20

So naturally, biber runs will fail:
ERROR - Error: Found biblatex control file version 3.10, expected version 3.11.
This means that your biber (2.20) and biblatex (3.19) versions are incompatible.

The archive that contains the backup (/usr/local/texlive/2024/tlpkg/backups/biber.r68188.tar.xz) contains a folder called biblatex-biber-2.19, so the backup revision (68188) does contain the version that I want (2.19).
How do I correctly downgrade the biber binary to 2.19 through tlmgr restore? I know that I could just grab the corresponding release from SourceForge and put it on my path but I was hoping for a more programmatic solution.

Not sure but you might be using the cached version. When Biber is updated, it regenerates the cache, but maybe it doesn't do that automatically in case of a downgrade. On my system, the binary is under /tmp/par-<very long meaningless string>/ but this will be system and, probably, session dependent. Rebooting would work, though I consider it a last resort ;).

@cfr Thanks for the pointer, but unfortunately for me, whence -s biber returns /Library/TeX/texbin/biber -> /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/biber, so it seems no cached version is being used. I have now resorted to manually backing up and replacing the binary in my texbin. Is there a cleaner way than manually replacing the binary, such as putting it somewhere on texmf-local, for example?

I don't understand exactly how it works, but when you use that binary it caches a temporary version which then gets used and can lead to the mismatch. On my system, which biber gives the version in /usr/local which is 32M and an executable. But there is also the unpacked version under /tmp which is 3.6M and also an executable. Basically, the large binary gets burst and unpacks a smaller binary and a whole bunch of library files etc. This is why the first run of after a reboot, say, takes longer. What does /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/biber --version return?

Why do you need to downgrade by the way? I'm just curious if there's some pitfall in the current version ....

@cfr I tried calling the executable directly at /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/biber --version which yielded the same results, unfortunately. As for your other question: I ran across a very specific bug that does not let me use the current version, but I assume that it does not affect too many other users. The bug has already been reported here: https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/1350

You mean it gives the old version or the new one?

@cfr Funnily enough, tlmgr does not seem to do anything to the binary. If I first run tlmgr restore and then /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/biber --version, it still shows 2.20. Contrarily, if I manually replace the 2.20 binary with the 2.19 version, run tlmgr update biber and then /usr/local/texlive/2024/bin/universal-darwin/biber --version, it still shows 2.19. I am now even more at a loss than before.

Manually replacing it probably explains the second. I suspect tlmgr, like most package managers, assumes its database reflects what is installed. If you change what is installed, the database isn't affected so it doesn't know. The first is odd, though. Have you asked on the TeX Live mailing list?
